# Assigning interpolated values to interpolated variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I had this in a method:

```
def create_data_arrays
    @local_result_hash.each do |job|
        @jobIds << job["jobId"]
        @employerNames << job["employerName"]
        @jobTitles << job["jobTitle"]
        @minimumSalarys << job["minimumSalary"]
        @maximumSalarys << job["maximumSalary"]
        @expirationDates << job["expirationDate"]
        @jobDescriptions << job["jobDescription"]
   end
end
```

And this in the main class:

```
@jobIds = []
@employerNames = []
@jobTitles = []
@minimumSalarys = []
@maximumSalarys = []
@expirationDates = []
@jobDescriptions = []
```

I wanted to refactor the method therefore I created the following array:

```
@api_parameters = ["jobId", "employerName", "jobTitle", "minimumSalary", "maximumSalary", "expirationDate", "jobDescription"]
```

And refactored the method to be:

```
def create_data_arrays
    @local_result_hash.each do |job|
        @api_parameters.each do |parameter|
            "@#{parameter}" << job[parameter]
        end
    end
end
```

Querying the hash works fine but `"@#{parameter}"` does not work. Suggestions? Am I doing something crazy?

Comment: Is `@local_result_hash` an array of hashes (in which case it is misnamed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `instance_variable_get`:

```
def create_data_arrays
  @local_result_hash.each do |job|
    @api_parameters.each do |parameter|
      instance_variable_get("@#{parameter}s") << job[parameter]
    end
  end
end
```

also see: apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get

Answer (score 1):

If `@local_result_hash` is in fact an array of hashes, as I expect, the following would be a Ruby-like way to create the instance variables.  I've taken some liberties in shortening the names of variables and keys, and deleting some key-value pairs, but have not changed the essence of the question.

Note that you do not need to initialize the instance variables (e.g., no `@jobIds = [];
@employerNames = []`, etc.) and you do not need the array `@api_parameters`.  This will make it easier to maintain the code if you add, delete or rename attributes.

**Code**

```
  def map_to_instance_vars(local_results)    
    local_results.first
                 .keys
                 .zip(local_results.map(&:values).transpose)
                 .each { |name,val| instance_variable_set("@#{ name }", val) }
  end
```

**Example**

```
  h1 = { "jobID"=>123, "title"=>"CEO", "description"=>"The big boss" }
  h2 = { "jobID"=>456, "title"=>"Supervisor", "description"=>"Push paper" }
  h3 = { "jobID"=>789, "title"=>"Flunkie", "description"=>"Do mindless work" }
  local_results = [h1, h2, h3]

  map_to_instance_vars(local_results)
  @jobID
    #=> [123, 456, 789]
  @title
    #=> ["CEO", "Supervisor", "Flunkie"]
  @description
    #=> ["The big boss", "Push paper", "Do mindless work"]
```

**Explanation**

Let `local_results` be as given in the example above. First skip ahead to the argument of [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip):

```
a = local_results.map(&:values)
  #=> [[123, "CEO", "The big boss"],
  #    [456, "Supervisor", "Push paper"],
  #    [789, "Flunkie", "Do mindless work"]]
b = a.transpose
  #=>  [[123, 456, 789],
  #     ["CEO", "Supervisor", "Flunkie"],
  #     ["The big boss", "Push paper", "Do mindless work"]]
```

Now create the object to which `zip` will be sent:

```
keys = local_results.first.keys
  #=> ["jobID", "title", "description"]
```

and send `keys` with argument `b` to it:

```
c = keys.zip(b) 
  #=> [["jobID", [123, 456, 789]],
  #    ["title", ["CEO", "Supervisor", "Flunkie"]],
  #    ["description", ["The big boss", "Push paper", "Do mindless work"]]]
```

Lastly, use [Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) to create an instance variable for each element of `c`:

```
c.each { |name,val| instance_variable_set("@#{ name }", val) }
@jobID
  #=> [123, 456, 789]
@title
  #=> ["CEO", "Supervisor", "Flunkie"]
@description
  #=> ["The big boss", "Push paper", "Do mindless work"]
```